# Mysql trigger statement keeps giving syntax error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I keep getting error messages when I try to execute this statement in phpmyadmin. I'm running mysql 5.7

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_counts_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tickets
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_uitvoeringId, V_ReserveringId varchar(50);
    DECLARE V_tekoop, V_gereserveerd, V_wachtlijst int;
    
    SET V_ReserveringId = NEW.reserveringId OR OLD.reserveringId;
    SET V_uitvoeringId = ( SELECT uitvoeringId FROM reservering WHERE id=V_ReserveringId )
    SET V_tekoop = (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM tickets t 
        WHERE t.tekoop AND NOT t.geannuleerd AND NOT t.verkocht AND t.uitvoeringId = V_uitvoeringId);

    SET V_gereserveerd =  (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM tickets t 
        WHERE NOT t.wachtlijst AND NOT t.geannuleerd AND NOT t.verkocht AND t.uitvoeringId = V_uitvoeringId);

    SET V_wachtlijst = (
        SELECT count(*) FROM tickets t WHERE t.wachtlijst AND NOT t.geannuleerd AND NOT t.verkocht AND t.uitvoeringId = V_uitvoeringId);

    update uitvoering 
        set tekoop = V_tekoop,       
            gereserveerd =  V_gereserveerd, 
            wachtlijst =  V_wachtlijst,
            vrije_plaatsen = aantal_plaatsen - V_gereserveerd + V_tekoop  
        WHERE id=V_uitvoeringId; 
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

- Unrecognized statement type. (near "DECLARE" at position 176)
- This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SET" at position 398)
- Unrecognized statement type. (near "END" at position 1192)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other syntax errors causing those complaints.

1. There is no `OR REPLACE` option with triggers in MySQL. The trigger must be dropped and then recreated.
2. There is no `OR`ing with actions, only one, which means that you'll have to create 3 triggers even though the definition may be the same. However, it seems like you only need an `AFTER UPDATE` action? ... because `AFTER INSERT` does not have an `OLD` reference, and `AFTER DELETE` does not have a `NEW` reference.
3. Getting past those two items, there is also a `;` missing after the query with `SELECT uitvoeringId`.

Putting all that together, becomes:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_counts_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON tickets
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE V_uitvoeringId, V_ReserveringId varchar(50);
    DECLARE V_tekoop, V_gereserveerd, V_wachtlijst int;
    
    SET V_ReserveringId = NEW.reserveringId OR OLD.reserveringId;
    SET V_uitvoeringId = ( SELECT uitvoeringId FROM reservering WHERE id=V_ReserveringId );
    SET V_tekoop = (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM tickets t 
        WHERE t.tekoop AND NOT t.geannuleerd AND NOT t.verkocht AND t.uitvoeringId = V_uitvoeringId);

    SET V_gereserveerd =  (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM tickets t 
        WHERE NOT t.wachtlijst AND NOT t.geannuleerd AND NOT t.verkocht AND t.uitvoeringId = V_uitvoeringId);

    SET V_wachtlijst = (
        SELECT count(*) FROM tickets t WHERE t.wachtlijst AND NOT t.geannuleerd AND NOT t.verkocht AND t.uitvoeringId = V_uitvoeringId);

    update uitvoering 
        set tekoop = V_tekoop,       
            gereserveerd =  V_gereserveerd, 
            wachtlijst =  V_wachtlijst,
            vrije_plaatsen = aantal_plaatsen - V_gereserveerd + V_tekoop  
        WHERE id=V_uitvoeringId; 
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Then with that in phpMyAdmin:

[image]

Then after executing the SQL:

[image]

Then checking the triggers tab:

[image]

...and clicking `Edit` at the trigger shows the definition:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had copied/modified the code from a Postgres SP that I use, but apparently there are quite a few differences in the syntax